# How to change a value of a select box after a previous change event has fired and loaded dynamic options into that select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok bear with me here, I may be trying to build the impossible or going about this the wrong way.

I have 2 select inputs `number1`, `number2` that are propagated dynamically from a `html()` on `ready()`. `number1` select already has the options in it when it is loaded and `number2` does not have the options loaded yet.

Then I first fire off `$('#number1').val(1).change();` change event so that it changes the value of the `number1` select and fires off the change event.

Then directly after I want to change the value of `number2` select with `$('#number2').val(2).change();` from the new dynamic options that were loaded.

The `number2` select is being loaded with the options, but `$('#number2').val(2).change();` is not changing them. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the DOM either not loaded yet with the new dynamic options OR the second `change` event is not firing.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#container').html('<select class="number1"><option value="0">Choose</option><option value="1">Number 1</option><option value="2">Number 2</option></select><select id="number2"></select>')

    $('.number1').val(1).change();
    $('.number2').val(2).change();

    $(document).on('change', '.number1', function() {
        // ajax call here that echos back the options for number2 select
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'blah/blah.php',
            data: {record: record},
            success: function (data) {
                $('.number2').html(data);
                // data echo's back <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
            }
        })
    })
    $(document).on('change', '.number2', function() {
        console.log('number2 change fired off!')
    })
})

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You execute `$("#number2").val(2).change()` before you've performed the AJAX request that loads the options into it.

Comment: You can't set the value to an option that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Chaining `.val()` and  `.change()` is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah I am beating a dead horse with this one. Time to rethink this

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that statement inside the callback that loads the options. Otherwise, you're executing it before the option with `value="2"` is loaded into the DOM, so it has no effect.

```
$(document).on('change', '.number1', function() {
    // ajax call here that echos back the options for number2 select
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'blah/blah.php',
        data: {record: record},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#number2').html(data);
            $('#number2').val(2).change();
        }
    })
})
```

Also, this line doesn't do anything:

```
$('#number1').val(1).change();
```

The first menu has `class="number1"`, not `id="number1"`.

And this doesn't do anything:

```
$(document).on('change', '.number2', function() {
    console.log('number2 change fired off!')
})
```

because the second menu has `id="number2"`, but not `class="number2"`.

You need to make sure your use of classes and IDs are consistent between the HTML and JS. Use classes for things that can appear multiple times and should all be treated similarly, IDs for things that are unique.

Comment: yeah I meant classes not id's sorry